# Adding animation to textview child of listview in a row

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview containing 10 rows. Each row has a textview and when I try to add a fade_out animation on the textview itself, animations only happen to listviews last item. I want to do it on all child textview.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        LayoutInflater in=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=in.inflate(R.layout.row_main, parent,false);



        titr=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_main_titr);
        matn=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_main_content);
        TextView extra=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_main_extra);
        ImageView image=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_main_image);


        titr.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        //titr.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        //titr.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET);



        ViewGroup.LayoutParams paramsi = image.getLayoutParams();
        paramsi.height= (W/2)-10;
        //image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        image.setLayoutParams(paramsi);


        image.setImageBitmap(img[position]);

        titr.setTextSize((float)W/35);

        titr.setText(name[position]);
        matn.setText(Html.fromHtml(content[position]).toString().replace("•", "\n"));
        extra.setText("نظرها: "+commentcount[position]);
        titr.setTypeface(yekan);

        matn.setTypeface(yekan);
        extra.setTypeface(MainActivity.koodak);


        return (row);
    }





}
```

and here I want to add animation

```
 // ShakeDetector initialization
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);


    mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector(new OnShakeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShake() {

            final Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), android.R.anim.fade_out);
            out.setDuration(300);
            out.setFillAfter(true);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tekun bede", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all I would like to say that adding animations in a listview can be a bad idea since they are continously recycled. That means are you are scrolling up and down the animation will continue to happen. Looking at your code, I would assume the issue is that you are using mShakeDetector as a class object. The issue might be that this is causing the previous animations to be overridden. I would recommend creating a local one in the getView method.

Like this, but you also need to do it for the other objects.

Sensor  mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: its so importent for me to use a senseo in another class

Comment: No in the adapter class, but make a new object for each view.